# VS Code: command-line error:missing source file name

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This is picture of my screen: [image: this is a picture of my screen.]This error shows up when I enter `#include <stdio.h>`to begin my program. I'm not sure how to fix this. Every file in Visual Studio Code is now having this issue.

I use gcc. gcc -o outputname filename.c and using C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing extension by Microsoft.

Comment: Please include more detail. Also don't just put the error message in the titel, please put the whole error message also in the question. You may want to read [ask]

Comment: @Ackdari I put everything in. I created a folder, created a file program.c then I enter in the #include <stdio.h> and that error shows up. That is all the error says.

Comment: Please add more details to your question (in the question text not the comments) otherwise we can not reproduce your problem and help you. You might want to read [MRE].

Comment: *Where* do you enter that? Please show some code, any command line instruction you type, the *full and exact* error message: flesh it out with some detail by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61046507/edit) the question. The error you quote seems to be a linker error.

Comment: @Ackdari uploaded a picture

Comment: We still need more details, for examle what command do you use to compile your c file or which vscode extension you use to compile it (and what settings this extensions has)

Comment: @Ackdari, sorry, I use gcc. gcc -o outputname filename.c and using C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing. extension by Microsoft.

Comment: My guess is you have set the default `INCLUDE_SEARCH_PATH` to find the gcc header files wherever they were installed on windows. You can also use the `-I` option to set that in the command line as well. If you have the include files in `C:\opt\include` then you can specify `-I/opt/include` to specify the search path.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't explain the question well.
I think that there is a macro in the build options that is not defined so it gets inserted into the build command as a blank string.  Does your project use some macros in the build options maybe something for 55x CSL directory?

If so make sure to define these macros on the macro tab of the build options dialog.

Comment: I have never had to do that. I have no clue where to start

Comment: First complete your whole program and then try to run it on any other online platform. If problem still exists, then update post here.

Answer (score 1):

Various things may contribute to this error:

- unclosed quotes in preprocessor definitions, macros or even c_cpp_properties.json
- file encoding
- the VS Code cpp extension

It has come and gone in my c/c++ development, and I don't know if anything specific I've done fixes it or if just restarting VS Code is the solution.

Most recently, I

1. changed the encoding of all files from UTF-8 to ANSI (in case there were any hidden unicode characters in the file, which happens with copy & paste sometimes)
2. restarted VS Code
3. it then complained that the c/c++ extension wasn't installed (it was?) and so I installed it again, and the error is gone.

Comment: the third case happened to me. the extension tried to auto update to a newest version, but failed. I followed the step 3, uninstalled and installed it again. worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I just uninstalled and reinstalled the c/c++ extension and it was back to normal

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem this morning. IntelliSense was at fault.
Only solution I quickly had found for me was to hard-delete C++ IntelliSense extension. Plain uninstall did not help.

You can remove IntelliSense Extension this way:

- close all instances of Visual Studio Code,
- navigate to folder `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- delete a folder/folders (incl. subfolders) ms-vscode.cpptools*
- start Visual Studio Code again and install fresh IntelliSense extension.

**NOTE**: you may lose your IntelliSense custom settings!